# Why does using Filestream to copy a file move quickly, then have long delay before completing?

Tags: vb.net, file, filestream

I am using a pair of io.filestreams to copy a file so I may monitor progress of the file as it is being copied. However, the copy rate seems to be strange compared to a system copy. The file is being copied from the local machine to a remote machine (with a UNC path) and seems consistent regardless of the machine.

For reference, if the file is copied via dragging and dropping the file, it takes approximately 13 seconds and the windows file copying progress bar reflects this accordingly.

If I copy the file with my code, the "progress bar" shows that all bytes were copied in one second, then there is approximately a 12 second delay while the filestream doing the reading closes.

I have tried flushing the streams during the writing but that does not seem to have any affect. Why are the bytes showing as written so quickly, then a delay happening as the code exits the Filestream Using loops?

Here is the method I am using:

```
Public Sub CopyFileInByteChunks(SourcePathFile As String, DestinationPathFile As String, NumberOf1KByteChunks As Long)

    Dim CopyBufferSize As Long = 1024 * 1024

    Console.WriteLine("START")
    Using sr = New IO.FileStream(SourcePathFile, IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Using sw = New IO.FileStream(DestinationPathFile, IO.FileMode.Create)
            Dim ThisFileBytesSoFar As Long = 0
            sw.SetLength(sr.Length) 'Ensures that the write out will be in contiguous bytes on the device (disk)
            Dim byteData(CopyBufferSize) As Byte
            Dim bytesRead As Long
            Do
                bytesRead = sr.Read(byteData, 0, CopyBufferSize) 'read 1 buffer worth of data
                ThisFileBytesSoFar += bytesRead 'for prog bar
                sw.Write(byteData, 0, bytesRead)
                Console.WriteLine(ThisFileBytesSoFar)
                If bytesRead = 0 Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
            Console.WriteLine("Completed Copy Loop")
        End Using
        Console.WriteLine("Exited Writer Using")
    End Using
    Console.WriteLine("Exited Reader Using")
End Sub
```

Comment: How large is your file?

Comment: Have you tried using Flush on each loop? Flush should properly send the data. Calling .Write can just put the information in memory without doing anything with it. Or try [AutoFlush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The test file is 1GB. As stated, .Flush has no affect on the code times. FileStream has no autoflush property that I can see.

Comment: [FileStream Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), Remarks section: *FileStream buffers input and output for better performance*. Also, try a buffer that doesn't exceed `0xFFFF` in a network copy (you didn't specify the systems types).

Comment: Both system in my example are Windows 10. Interesting that the documentation. Yes, I assumed that the FileStream was buffering somehow, but expected the .Flush to have an effect on the process (which it does not). I will try a smaller buffer and monitor the process again to see if buffer size has any impact on the closing/disposing of the stream next.